# Unfound packages in yeoman

Tags: installation, package, fatal-error, yeoman, bower

Im trying to install socket.io throu yeoman, it loads sockets just fine when then I guess it tries to load up the dependencies and it can't find them and gives me fatal error  ws not found (for the ws package).
It's trying to fetch from theses urls:

1. bower.herokuapp.com/packages/uglify-js
2. bower.herokuapp.com/packages/ws
3. bower.herokuapp.com/packages/xmlhttprequest
4. bower.herokuapp.com/packages/active-x-obfuscator

and it's cant find the links to GIT. i've tried to load the addresses but there is no response from the server.

Any idea how I can fix that problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`socket.io` is not a valid Bower component. [I've request it be removed from the registry](https://github.com/twitter/bower/issues/120#issuecomment-13268634).

It's a [component](https://github.com/component/component) component, not a Bower component. (confusing, I know...).

Comment: AH ok, thanks for that mate. But here is what Im trying to achieve.
I need to use Node.js and socket.io for my project but I'd also like to use the scafolding provided by yeoman. And while the yeoman server runs I want to update even the app.js file when I modify it. Is that possible?

Comment: It might, but will be hard. We've made it much easier in Yeoman 1.0 which is imminent.